# Why do rspec filter hooks only work with arrow syntax?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, automated-tests

In RSpec tests, I'm using hooks/flags to run subsets of tests, similar to what is shown in the [examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/filtering/exclusion-filters)

```
# spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.filter_run_excluding('broken')
end
```

This syntax works

```
# my_spec.rb
describe 'broken test', 'broken' => true do
  ...
end
```

This syntax fails with error `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input`

```
# my_spec.rb
describe 'broken test', 'broken': true do
  ...
end
```

What is the difference between them which causes one to work and the other to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example

```
{'broken' => true}
# => {"broken" => true}
```

creates a Hash with a String as the key. When you use the colon syntax however, the hash will have a Symbol key:

```
{'broken': true} # This is only valid syntax since Ruby 2.2
# => {:broken => true}

{broken: true}
# => {:broken => true}
```

Since you are specifically excluding specs marked with a String key, the symbol won't match.

You can either change your rspec config to

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.filter_run_excluding(:broken)
end
```

or continue to use String keys in your specs.

*As a tiny post scriptum: the colon-syntax with a quoted string you used in your first spec example is only valid since Ruby 2.2. Older Ruby versions produce the syntax error you quote in your (edited) question.*